# Hibernate Entity doesnt work for Oracle PLSQL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, plsql, entity, persistence

first of all sorry for my English.

hi everyone i want to make web Project with eclipse. I want to try java, hibernate, entity, serializable, oracle plsql vs...

i little learn entity , Java, Entity hibernate but i connect to apex But  there is  entity and serializable on my Java class. but Eclipse  Doesnt create table automatic on Oracle Plsql(APEX).

i know, Entity is automatic create table on database
i made for MySQL  but Oracle PLSQL i cannot make

```
My Entity Class

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Lesson")
 public class Lesson implements java.io.Serializable 


My Hibernate.xml
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">
    false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
    oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
   ...<property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
    ...</property>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

[Table doesnt exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTV2a.png)[2](http://postimg.org/image/bbhqbny0n/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case

> ORA-00942 Table or view doesn't exist

First things to do

### Check if table has a synonym (Oracle table names are case sensitive in system views):

```
SELECT * from all_synonyms where table_name='LESSON';
```

---

If it doesn't, you can either specify the schema where the table abide, or create a synonym for it.

### On which table is my schema?

```
SELECT owner from all_tables where table_name='LESSON';
```

=> this gives you **`<schema name>`** to use in further commands

---

### Either specify table's schema in hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Lesson", schema = "<schema name>")
public class Lesson implements java.io.Serializable 
...
```

### Or create a synonym for it

```
create synonym LESSON for <schema name>.LESSON;
```

hope it helps...